# What determines where gems are installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to set up a Sinatra app on my web host. I don't have sudo rights to install gems in the system-wide path, which is several subfolders beneath `/usr/local`, but I do have a `gems` folder in my app's directory.

### Background

[This reference](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12) gives the following definitions:

- `GEM_HOME` - "Directory containing the master gem repository."
- `GEM_PATH` - "Path list of directories containing gem repositories to be searched in addition to the GEM_HOME directory. The list should be delimited by the appropriate path separator (e.g. ‘:’ on Unix and ‘;’ on Windows)"

### Initial settings on login

When I first ssh into this web host, `echo $GEM_HOME` and `echo $GEM_PATH` both produce an empty string, but `gem list` shows several gems.

### Trying to change gem location

From the command line, I have set `GEM_HOME` like this:

```
GEM_HOME=$PWD/gems # 'gems' folder under present working directory
echo $GEM_HOME     # correctly outputs the gem folder I specified
ls $GEM_HOME       # shows gems folder contents, namely: 
                   # bin/ cache/ docs/ gems/ specifications/
```

I also set `GEM_PATH` to the same folder.

After doing this, `gem list` still shows global gems rather than the gems in the specified folder, and `gem install` still tries to install to the global location.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: can you use rvm, makes life easy in many situations.

Comment: @three - I do use rvm at work on my development machine, which may be why I'm not clear on how to do this manually. However, it seems like overkill in this situation. Also, I want to understand what rvm is doing for me, anyway, so doing it myself once in a while seems good.

Comment: First thing I would check is that it's not a shell issue... if you're remoting into a host machine with constraints on the shell.  For instance, try `GEM_HOME=$PWD/gems gem list`. You should see a list of gems in the PWD/gems directory.  If that's the case, try `export GEM_HOME=$PWD/gems` or add this variable to your shell's profile/exports script (.bashrc, .bash_profile, or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

There is no manpage for `gem`, which doesn't make it easier. I assume `GEM_PATH` is where to look for the gems, and `GEM_HOME` is where to install them. Try

```
export GEM_HOME = "$GEM_PATH"
```

Comment: I did find a reference for these variables here: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12

Comment: It's the other way around, actually.

Answer (score 2):

## Use 'export'

Looks like `export`, as Tass showed, was the missing piece: it makes my local `GEM_HOME` variable a global one.

Here's what I've done:

```
export GEM_HOME=$PWD/gems       # where to install and look for gems
export PATH=$PWD/gems/bin:$PATH # append the gems' binaries folder to
                                # the current path, so that I can call
                                # `bundle install` and have it find
                                # myapp/gems/bin/bundle
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that one and therefore considered my answer trivial after rereading your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bundler as well.  Bundler makes it very easy to manage Gem versions, even when sudo access is not possible.  You create a file called `Gemfile` in the root of your application and put lines such as these:

```
gem "sinatra"
gem "some_other_gem_dependency"
gem "and_so_on_and_so_forth", ">= 1.0"
```

And then run `bundle install --path /where/you/want/your/gems/stored` which will install the gems to a path you have access to.  You then put this in your config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require
require './your_app'
run YourApp
```

Check out http://gembundler.com/sinatra.html for more info.

Comment: I am using Bundler, but I didn't know you could specify an installation path. Nice tip.